# Cannot install applications from the store

Tags: nao-robot, pepper

When I try to install applications from the store in my Pepper robot I encounter the following problems (please refer to the screenshots bellow).

[image: store]

[image: applications]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The store (screenshot 1) is japan-only.
The apps (screenshot 2) looks like Nao apps.

Edit:
You can try and navigate to 
https://cloud.aldebaran-robotics.com/application/
and filter by Pepper
[image]

Comment: + don't hesitate to [contact support](https://account.aldebaran.com/support/) if you experience issues with your account